# Able to Import my Account from Geth to MetaMask but No Balance Shown

Tags: go-ethereum, balances, import

I'm able to mined to my Accounts in Geth and have successfully imported to MetaMask. Problem, is in my Geth Console, I have the balance of the Mined Accounts but after imported to MetaMask, the Balance shows Zero.

> eth.accounts[0]
> "0x1345cdae234bb113e22ba7a4011c59b1817df8a8"

> eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0])
> 606000000000000000000

Need help in this, thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kn07t.png)
[image]

Comment: I checked on Etherscan and your account does not hold ethers (https://etherscan.io/address/0x1345cdae234bb113e22ba7a4011c59b1817df8a8)

Comment: Are you mining on a testnet or private blockchain ?

Comment: I'm mining using Mainnet in Geth Terminal

Comment: jsjs77@Sims-MacBook-Pro myeth-web3 % ./bin/geth --datadir=./datadir console --rpc --rpccorsdomain="chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn"
INFO [04-04|20:49:48.471] Starting Geth on Ethereum mainnet... 
INFO [04-04|20:49:48.471] Bumping default cache on mainnet         provided=1024 updated=4096
INFO [04-04|20:49:48.475] Maximum peer count                       ETH=50 LES=0 total=50
WARN [04-04|20:49:48.475] The flag --rpc is deprecated and will be removed June 2021, please use --http 
WARN [04-04|20:49:48.475] The flag --rpccorsdomain is deprecated

Comment: @Jsim Sorry but you are not mining on Ethereum mainnet. Check if node has synchronized with `eth.syncing` and the latest block number `eth.blockNumber` should be close to the latest block on any block explorer.

Comment: Okay noted with thanks, and will check that.