# I am able to import account from private blockchain to Metamask but there is no balance shown

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, ether, metamask, private-blockchain

I know there is a question with very similar title [posted here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/96684/able-to-import-my-account-from-geth-to-metamask-but-no-balance-shown) but my question is a bit different.

In my scenario, I created a private blockchain and created an account there with some funds.

So in my private blockchain if I type `eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase)` I get `9.04625697166532776746648320380374280103671755200316906558262375061821325312e+74`

Now I connected to this private blockchain using metamask and I imported this account successfully.

I can see the account and network in metamask, and it says connected too. However against the imported account it says `"0 ETH $0.00 USD"`.

Due to this I am unable to deploy my contract to my private blockchain since I get a message `Insufficient funds`.

Can someone help me in guiding me on how I can get metamask to see my balance as well?

Any help is much appreciated.